# Re-use themed style blocks within a Material-UI components styles

Tags: material-ui

Thinking of the concept of a SASS mixin, what would be the best approach to enable the re-use of style blocks that incorporate the current theme.

For example I have two components that import their respective styles:

- Component 1

  - index
  - styles
- Component 2

  - index
  - styles

Each component has a text block

**Component 1**

```
import { styles } from './styles'
....
<div className={classes.richText}>...</div>
```

**Component 2**

```
import { styles } from './styles'
....
<div className={classes.richText}>...</div>
```

The styles for richText are the same but I would rather not duplicate them in the imported styles file.

I would rather have a single file that exposes reusable CSS properties based on the theme.

The only way I can currently do this is by returning an object that I have passed the theme to e.g.

```
const RichText = (theme) => {
 return {
  fontWeight: 100,
  color: theme.typography.body1.color
 }
}
```

Then import this into the styles

**Component 1**

styles.js

```
import { RichText } from '../mixins/'

const styles = theme => ({
 richText: {
  ...RichText(theme),
  fontSize: '1rem'
 }
```

**Component 2**

styles.js

```
import { RichText } from '../mixins/'

const styles = theme => ({
 richText: {
  ...RichText(theme),
  fontSize: '1.2rem'
 }
```

Feels like there has to be a better way: utilising withTheme() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to custom a checkbox as below:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CheckBox from '@material-ui/core/CheckBox';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.status.danger,
    '&$checked': {
      color: theme.status.danger,
    },
  },
  checked: {},
}));

function CustomCheckbox() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Checkbox
      defaultChecked
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        checked: classes.checked,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

And you want to reuse its style as many components as you can.

You have two options: `ThemeProvider` or export your custom style.

#### Changing the component's theme

> Themes let you apply a consistent tone to your app. It allows you to customize all design aspects of your project in order to meet the specific needs of your business or brand.

```js
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import orange from '@material-ui/core/colors/orange';

const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  status: {
    danger: orange[500],
  },
});

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
      <CustomCheckbox />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

#### Exporting your custom styles

Separate your components in a proper folder, i.e: `./assets/styles`:

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const useCheckBoxStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.status.danger,
    '&$checked': {
      color: theme.status.danger,
    },
  },
  checked: {},
}));
```

And your components tree `./components`:

```js
import { useCheckBoxStyles } from './assets/styles';

function CustomCheckbox() {
  const classes = useCheckBoxStyles();

  return (
    <Checkbox
      defaultChecked
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        checked: classes.checked,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

#### References

https://material-ui.com/customization/theming